# Format URLs to the common pattern

Tags: javascript, url, web-scraping

I'm using [x-ray](https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray) for web-scraping.
Scraped data is storing into database, including URL.
URLs acts as unique key to prevent duplicating data.
But, the same url could looks different:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#element  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/  
stackoverflow.com/questions/ask  
www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask  
etc.
```

Is it possible to retrive some kind of 'real' url through x-ray or somehow else to make stored url looks always exactly the same?
May be, there are some regular expressions (js), which could bring any url to the common format?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: well the anchor tag is easy, but redirects aren't detectable without comparing content

Comment: sorry, i don't get it

Comment: i think this topic was about the function i need:  
https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray/issues/17  
but i don't get, where i can find more info about this

Comment: Is it something you could try? https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561

Comment: You can try [this](https://github.com/unshiftio/url-parse) module.